XGBoost Binary Classification for authentication hyperparameter tuning
Im currently working on biometric authentication, specifically on keystroke dynamics. I used XGBoost as binary classification so i can calculate equal error rate (EER) and ROC-AUC. Now i want to do tuning hyperparameter but i dont know how should set them up. My current approach was wraping XGBoost with OneVsRestClassifier then use gridsearchcv with roc_auc_ovr scoring? is this the correct approch?

Show us what your current results look like. Include a confusion matrix. It's unclear why roc_auc_ovr scoring would be a good match to your Business Problem. How do {correct, incorrect} classifications show up in the UX? Are we continuously computing a probability based on window of last twenty keystrokes? Is the legitimate user given some opportunity to cast a saving throw upon being rejected? What is the cost of incorrectly classifying as "authorized", and is it identical to the cost of an incorrect "not authorized" classification?
